# Auth. Providers Facebook Existing (community) User Linking

Tags: apex, oauth

I'm currently adding a Facebook login to our customer onboarding process that we host through Salesforce.

I have got it working for existing users already, if their Facebook email is the same as their Salesforce username. See below for my (shortened) implementation:

```
global class OAuthProviderRegistrationHandler implements Auth.RegistrationHandler {
global Void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data) { }
global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data) {
    return (User)[SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Username = :data.email LIMIT 1][0];
}
```

}

I activate the code above with the url (Single Sign-On Initialization): https://test.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/{org_id}/Facebook_SSO?community={community_login_url}, and it works great.

I tried linking the accounts with the url (Existing User Linking): https://test.salesforce.com/services/auth/link/{org_id}/Facebook_SSO?community={community_login_url}.

But after logging into facebook, and the community site I got redirected to the following url {my_salesforce_sandbox}/_nc_external/identity/sso/ui/AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=Invalid_param

What does these error code "Invalid_param" mean?

Just to be clear Single Sign-On Initialization Url is working fine, but I get the above error using the Existing User Linking Url.

Comment: I know this an old question but I saw this error when the developer name of my auth provider was incorrect. I was also using a AuthConfiguration method. E.g. The developer name of my auth provider was "AuthProviderDev" but I used "AuthProviderdev," which produced the correct SSO url but had the auth provider name incorrect.